# Is there a wildcard character I can use to solve this?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I have a simple problem but I'm stuck.

I need to search a string for the text "bob", except the "o" can be any character. 
Is there a wildcard character I can use, or another simpler method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might start with the relevant javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Also see, [Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method with the right regex:

```
if (str.matches(".*b.b.*"))
```

Note that the regex must match the *whole* string to return `true`.

If you want to match the *word* "bob", you'll need "word boundaries":

```
if (str.matches("(?i).*\\bb[a-z]b\\b.*"))
```

Note that the "case insensitive" flag has been added to allow any case to match.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches a whole word starting and ending with 'b' with any alpha-numeric (or underscore) character between:

```
\bb\wb\b
```

To match any *lowercase letter* between, use

```
\bb[a-z]b\b
```

To match any *letter* between, use

```
\bb[a-zA-Z]b\b
```

To escape these for Java strings, change each \ to \\